# How to control space length between lines of double-underline?

Tags: spacing, ulem

I use `\uuline` command from `ulem` package to make double-underlined text. I would like to know if it is possible to control space length between lines? I drew below what I mean. If not, how to make custom double-underline with space length controlled? [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space between the double lines is hard-coded: 1.2pt, see the definition of `\uuline` in package `ulem`.

The following example changes the definition in two ways:

- The hard-coded space is replaced by dimen register `\uulinesep`.
- Also the top line is aligned, not the bottom line. This avoids that the top line overprints the descenders or even moves above the base line, when `\uulinesep` is increased too much.

The depth of the whole double line can be changed by setting `\ULdepth` as shown in the second and third line of the example. The default is `\maxdimen`. Then package `ulem` uses the depth of `j()`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\newdimen\uulinesep
\setlength{\uulinesep}{1.2pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\uuline}{%
  \bgroup
  \UL@setULdepth
  \markoverwith{%
    \lower\ULdepth\hbox{%
      \kern-.03em%
      \vtop{%
        \hrule width.2em%
        \kern\uulinesep
        \hrule
      }%
      \kern-.03em%
    }%
  }%
  \ULon
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\uulinesep}{#1}%
    \uuline{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\test{0pt} \test{0.6pt} \uuline{1.2pt}\,\uline{(default)}
\test{2pt} \test{1ex}

\newcommand*{\testA}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\ULdepth}{#1}%
    \addtolength{\ULdepth}{.4pt}% line width
    \uuline{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\testB}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \settodepth{\ULdepth}{#1}%
    \addtolength{\ULdepth}{.4pt}% line width
    \uuline{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\testA{0pt} \testA{1.5pt} \testA{1pt} \testA{2pt} \testA{4pt}

\testB{j} \testB{()} \testB{x} \testB{$\int_0^\infty$}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]