# overlapping underline

Tags: formatting, text-decorations

I would like to underline all occurrences of a factor that appears in a text, e. g. all occurrences of `aba` in `text=abaababa`

If I use underline, I won't see clearly the three occurrences so what I need is a package which allows me to use overlapping `\underline{}`.

I did it in the past and it worked well (it's therefore feasible) but I'm getting old now and I don't remember how I did it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261496/10898

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a package for overlapping underline, but I once solved this by using regular underline and `\vphantom{}` for lowering parts of the line. With `\vphantom{}` you can make sure the lines don't overlap, but are spaced underneath each other.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}

\underline{aba}\underline{ab\underline{\vphantom{\_}a}}\underline{ba}

\end{document}
```

This should give you the right underlining. If necessary you can use `\vphantom{p}` for more vertical space. Note that you would be 'sticking' two underlines together for the last `aba`, rather then making one. You will notice that if you replace the underscore with a `p`.

Comment: Is ulem package required with \underline{}?

Comment: Many thanks, it is exactly what I needed. Laurent