# How to automatically leave lines for translation

Tags: line-breaking, rules

I would like to enter a paragraph within a command and, each time it would go onto a new line, leave space and horizontal lines for translation. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this automatically. I've manually created a version of what I mean. As you can see, doing it manually does not make for elegant justification.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\translationlines}{\vspace*{2em}\hrule\vspace*{2em}\hrule\vspace*{2em}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id dictum nisi, 

\translationlines

\noindent nec interdum enim. Phasellus eros lacus, interdum ac eros et, luctus suscipit 

\translationlines

\noindent risus. Suspendisse accumsan consequat libero, eleifend sagittis lorem aliquam  

\translationlines

\noindent ut. Nulla facilisi. Ut ante enim, pharetra ut faucibus nec, sagittis ac leo.  

\translationlines

\noindent Nunc sollicitudin facilisis velit, a elementum est convallis quis. Sed eget leo  

\translationlines


\end{document}
```

[image: manual version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from the great answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261496/36296 you could missus a double underline:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\setlength{\ULdepth}{2.5\baselineskip}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\uuline}{%
  \bgroup
  \UL@setULdepth
  \markoverwith{%
    \lower\ULdepth\hbox{%
      \kern-.03em%
      \vtop{%
        \hrule width.2em%
        \kern\ULdepth
        \hrule
        \kern\ULdepth
      }%
      \kern-.03em%
    }%
  }%
  \ULon
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent\uuline{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id dictum nisi, nec interdum enim. Phasellus eros lacus, interdum ac eros et, luctus suscipit risus. Suspendisse accumsan consequat libero, eleifend sagittis lorem aliquam  ut. Nulla facilisi. Ut ante enim, pharetra ut faucibus nec, sagittis ac leo.  Nunc sollicitudin facilisis velit, a elementum est convallis quis. Sed eget leo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stunning! Thanks so much. I'll add an \hfill at the end because the partial ruled lines look odd to me - but brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: @alice19 The `\hfill` is a good idea! I was actually wondering how to fill the gap at the end :)